# Compiling External Dependencies in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, external-dependencies

I have an issue migrating a Visual C++ project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2015. The project I am migrating is perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2008, but upon migration I experience compile errors in the External Dependencies, I think some of the function definitions and macros are not recognized in the headers which are found in the External Dependencies. Is there a way to compile these External Dependencies? Or is there an option in the Project properties which I have missed on setting.

Comment: You don't normally *compile* the external dependencies, at least not separately Those are just header files that your project uses. You need to add the path to those files to your VS 2015's project settings.

Comment: *"I experience compile errors ..."* - what errors? Please show us some examples.

Comment: Hi Cody, the path of the headers are already set in Configuration Properties>VC++ Environment Variables. Do I also need to include the path for the source files?

Hi Roger, for the compile errors I experience compile errors like error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'

below are the sample codes:

char far * _System Foo(int);

Comment: I would just like to add that far and _System is defined using a macro. I used the macro in the actual code which is also defined in other external dependencies.